# Laravel 5.4 Authentication to a different table not working

Tags: laravel, authentication

In my laravel application, I need to make a  login to `customers` table. So, I made a `CustomerLoginController`.

My `CustomerLoginController` looks like:

```
class CustomerLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the data

            $this->validate($request,[
               'email' => 'required|email',
               'password' => 'required'
            ]);

            $credentials=[
                'email' => $request->get('email'),
                'password' => $request->get('password')
            ];



        // Log The Customer In

        if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt(['email'=> $request['email'],'password' => $request['password']]))
        {
            // If Authentication passed...
            dd($credentials);
            return redirect(route('first'));
        }

        // If Authentication not successful, redirect back to login form with the inputs

        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username()));
    }

public function username()
{
    return 'email';
}
```

I have setup the `customer` guard and providers in the `config/Auth.php`. My `config/Auth.php` file:

```
  'guards' => [
            'web' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],

            'customer' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'customers',
            ],

            'api' => [
                'driver' => 'token',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],
        ],



        'providers' => [
            'users' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => App\User::class,
            ],

            'customers' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => App\Models\Customer::class,
            ],


        ],
```

The Problem is that even when the credentials are correct the login attempt is always unsuccessful.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you implemented the customer guard?

Comment: I have only implemented customer guard before the attempt method. Is there anywhere else, I should have implemented it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what about Customer Model.

it should extend Authenticatable same as User Model.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
/* your code */
}
class Customer extends Authenticatable
/* your code */
{
}
```

and Don't Forgot to use Authenticatable in Model. :)

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
```

Comment: Yes, I have extended authenticable in both user and customer model.

Comment: Okay, I hadn't hashed the password in the database and that was all that was about it. Thanks.